# When was first line detection algorithm created and when line detection problem was posed?

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, image-processing, cv.computer-vision

I wonder when was first line detection algorithm created (first used in practice and refrenced by any publications) and when line detection problem was posed (I know it can look like generaal edge detection problem but it is quite more complex than that)?

Well... some students (including me) were trained that line detection is achevable by Hough transform. [Wiki history page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform#History) talls us that The Hough transform was patented as `U.S. Patent 3,069,654` in 1962 and assigned to the U.S. and he used it scince 1959...   and that is not even problem posting - thats like a solution... so... What shall I do? Who posted the problem, formalized it?

BTW: [Here (IEEE library)](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/search/freesearchresult.jsp?queryText=line%20detection&openedRefinements=%2a&searchField=Search%20All&sortType=asc_Publication%20Year&pageNumber=1&resultAction=SORT) search results sorted by date (oldest -> newest)... (I see Straight-line detection with diodes: this 1934 year)

Comment: More details on those two problems would be welcome. And what are the earliest references you have found?

Comment: Is the edge detection problem more complex than the line detection problem, or the other way round?  It might be worth clarifying your phrasing, and see also @Anthony's comments.

Comment: So it seems that "line detection" here refers to a problem in digital image processing, i.e., detecting features that resemble lines in two-dimensional raster images (bitmaps). It would have been helpful to make this explicit...